# Adding custom map tile layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, tiles, web-mercator

I am trying to display the following background map in QGIS 2.0:
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}.
In a custom web map client, this is quite easy:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/xyz-esri.html

I tried to use the "OpenLayers plugin" in QGIS, but there the list of background tile maps is predefined and I cannot add my own custom map tile layer.

Is there any easy workaround (without any programming) how I could show the custom map tiles layer in QGIS?

Comment: I get the error "Could not draw [TMS NAME] because:" on a computer with QGIS 2.2.0 on Windows 7: I get the TMS list successfully, I can add one to my project and I can see but any pan or zoom throw the error. In another pc with Windows XP (and also QGIS 2.2.0) everythings work fine! I really don't understand where the problem could be! Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: With QGIS 2.2.0 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 all works fine. But I get the same error as you on Windows 7.

Comment: The TileLayer plugin appears to be working fine both on Windows 7 and on Linux in QGIS 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, TileLayerPlugin is compatible with QGIS versions **2.8 - 2.99**

So, the other option to add custom tiles stored locally on disk - 
fill in URL (I use Linux, for Windows I suppose you have to change backslashes):

```
file:///path/to/your/custom/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 7):

Try the new `Tile Layer Plugin`.

The tile sources are stored in a tab delimitered text file. You can add sources as you want.

For the Arcgis tiles, try:

```
Arcgis  Arcgis  http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png   1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

(note that this site's software has turned the tabs into blanks)

[image]

Comment: OK, I installed the Tile Layer Plugin. Where is the tab delimited text file? I only found .qgis2/python/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/layers/frame.tsv but when I add the Arcgis source I get an error: "Invalid line format: frame.tsv line 3"

Comment: Under `Settings` you can choose an `External layers directory`. Every .tsv file found there will be read and interpreted. I don't know what the frame.tsv is for, better restore it unchanged.

Comment: I made progress: I created a new file .qgis/python/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/layers/arcgis.tsv. Then I added the Arcgis source information to the arcgis.tsv file. Now the tile map is displayed same as in your screenshot. But when I try to zoom in, I get an error "Could not draw Arcgis because:"

Comment: Strange, I never saw that error. Maybe you should ask the author about it. You are in EPSG:3857? Cam you first load a shapefile, zoom to the extent and then add the Arcgis layer?

Comment: I tried the TileLayerPlugin with QGIS on a second computer and everything worked perfectly. So, my error on the first computer is probably a bug and I'll try to ask the author about it.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [QuickMapService](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin. You can [create](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgis-lab.info%2Fqa%2Fquickmapservices.html&edit-text=) custom service definition, and save it in user dir of QMS.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with QGIS 2.18, there is a new feature called "Tile Server (XYZ)" in the QGIS Browser Panel that lets you easily establish a link to an online tile server without requiring additional plugins. Just right-click the button, choose "New Connection..." and insert the URL for [Esri World Topographic Map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6e850093c837475e8c23d905ac43b7d0):

[image: tile-server-xyz]

After choosing a name for the tile layer (not shown; "Esri WorldTopoMap" in the example below), double-click the newly created tile server to add it to the QGIS Layers Panel. A more detailed description can be found [here](http://felix.rohrba.ch/en/2017/easily-add-tilemap-layers-qgis/), among many others.

[image: tile-server-xyz(2)]

Answer (score 2):

Please read the simple and complete tilelayer plugin howto docs:

https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin