# Adding custom web tile layer to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tiles, mapbox, tile-layer

I would like to use a basemap from the Ancient World Mapping Centre, available as maptiles via Mapbox, as basemap in my ArcMap desktop version 10.2.2.

It is possible to add a *web tile layer* to ArcGIS online as described in:

- [Using Stamen and MapBox tilesets as basemaps in ArcGIS.com](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/)

Is there a similar solution to add a custom map tile layer to ArcMap as in the question underneath?

[Adding custom map tile layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82075/how-to-add-a-custom-map-tile-layer/174564#174564)

Note: I am looking for a solution that's not using external pluggin or ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Maybe [ArcBrutile](https://arcbrutile.codeplex.com) can help you? I haven't used it myself yet, but Mapbox is mentioned as one of the supported formats.

Comment: I would like to add a custom basemap in ArcMap too. Have you found a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I am using 10.2.2 and as far as I have been able to tell, there is no equivalent to the (rather excellent) way you can do this in QGIS.

The only option is to save a custom map layer on ArcGIS online and then connect to it using the '**Add data from ArcGIS online**' option in the Add Data tab. Otherwise you are restricted to the generic base maps provided by ESRI.

In Arcmap:

**File > Add Data > Add data from ArcGIS online..**

Comment: Thank you Alex. I'm afraid I do not own the tiles I want to use, so I can't save the map layer to my content.

Answer (score 4):

Update for September 2017:

This is pretty straighforward at this point (finally). You don't need to "own" the tiles to do this, only add the tile service to an ArcGIS online webmap (Add --> Layer From Web) like so:

[image: Add tile service]

After that, save the webmap (not the tiles themselves) to your "Content". Then go to Content, and click on the map:

[image: My content page]

This will bring up the page for your particular webmap:

[image: Saved webmap]

From here, you can click `Open in ArcGIS Desktop`. This will download a mysterious `item.pkinfo` file, which when clicked will open ArcMap with the tile service displayed.

Comment: This isn't working for me currently - I can add the tiles fine but the 'Open in ArcGIS Desktop' button is not shown on the page (which otherwise looks the same as shown). I also tried manually creating a .pkinfo file with the appropriate id and the tiles don't come through when opening the file in ArcMap. Perhaps you need a paid account for this to work?

Comment: hey @snorris - yeah, looks like that button no longer exists. Not cool. Can you try creating your own item.pkinfo file based on this example?
 https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/199029/30899

Comment: I tried that - the .pkinfo file worked to display another layer in the AGOL map (esri world topo), but my tiles didn't come through. I installed and configured mapproxy to serve my tiles as a WMS instead. https://mapproxy.org/

Comment: Hmm - strange. Just tested it myself and was able to view my layer with that .pkinfo hack. My pkinfo file is here: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><pkinfo><ID>d4b66bc68b6d4a4e8c1c535b71c2f938</ID><size>-1</size><created>1381949303000</created><type>Web Map</type><packagelocation>http://www.arcgisonline.com/sharing/content/items/d4b66bc68b6d4a4e8c1c535b71c2f938/data</packagelocation><pkinfolocation>http://www.arcgisonline.com/sharing/content/items/d4b66bc68b6d4a4e8c1c535b71c2f938/item.pkinfo</pkinfolocation></pkinfo>`

Comment: But @snorris if mapproxy works then that sounds like a great solution to me.

Comment: Update for Feb 2019 - the `Open in ArcGIS Desktop` button is back...