# What is *.pkinfo file?

Tags: arcgis-online, file-formats, map-package, pkinfo

What is a `*.pkinfo` file?

Google Search results talk about Package Info files and how they contain map documents and layers, so I don't see how this is different from a .mpk file.

I also have not found anything about how to create a `*.pkinfo` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .pkinfo file is an xml file that hold the Arcgis online unique map id hash.
For example, [this AGOL map](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2f382d5fcdb748deba89e6104b59551d) has the id `2f382d5fcdb748deba89e6104b59551d`

The <kbd>Open in Arcgis Desktop</kbd> option downloads a **pkinfo** file locally, and this is what it reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><pkinfo><ID>2f382d5fcdb748deba89e6104b59551d</ID><size>-1</size><created>1381949303000</created><type>Web Map</type><packagelocation>http://www.arcgisonline.com/sharing/content/items/2f382d5fcdb748deba89e6104b59551d/data</packagelocation><pkinfolocation>http://www.arcgisonline.com/sharing/content/items/2f382d5fcdb748deba89e6104b59551d/item.pkinfo</pkinfolocation></pkinfo>
```

It's just a url and an item id that opens the web service/layers inside ArcMap

Comment: Can I save it as shapefile on my system?

Comment: after you open the link in ArcMap you should be able to save it locally as shapefile. However if you have access to the link and map and data, then saving locally is possibly a redundant activity?