# Opening ArcGIS Online files without ArcMap gives error 403?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-package

Although the topic about pkinfo was addressed in the question [What is *.pkinfo file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197144/what-is-pkinfo-file) on this occasion it does not matter about "what is a pkinfo file" but rather if there is any solution to the problem of the "error 403" message after following the instructions on the support page from esri https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011109

I tried to open a item.pkinfo file without ArcMap, following the steps detailed in Esri support page, Meaning :

Open  the item.pkinfo file with notepad and copy the URL between  tags

When I go to the specified URL, I get this message:

"You do not have permissions to access this resource or perform this operation. error 403"

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: From the answer at the duplicate with my bolding: "It's just a url and an item id that opens the web service/layers **inside ArcMap**"

Comment: Hi, why this question was marked as duplicated and answered whit " What is *.pkinfo file?" it seems to me that they are two different consults that need totally diferent answers

Comment: If you don't provide the URL in question, there isn't really anything *we* can do.  In fact, there isn't *any* way we can make a server that doesn't want to talk to you do so.

Comment: Until you added a link to the "Esri support page" that you mentioned originally, I assumed that it was just a page saying how to use a `*.pkinfo` in ArcMap.

Comment: But in the original post i specified in a resume way the steps  i follow that are detailed inside the page. Any way still dont understand why its a duplicate question, regards

Comment: A 403 error is a permission issue, nothing at all to do with successfully parsing the .pkinfo

Comment: What URL did you get from the pkinfo and try to go to?