# Converting .pkinfo file into shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, pkinfo

I have to save a .pkinfo file on my computer. However, I could not find that option in ArcMap.

Is there a way to save this kind of file on my system and have access to edit it as well?

Comment: If you wish to ask a similar question about doing this in QGIS then please use a new question so that this one can be focused on ArcMap.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197144/what-is-pkinfo-file